# Reverse order of hex std::string

Tags: c++

I'm working with an old program and need help **swapping the order of a Hex String**.

Yes, a string...as in:

```
string hexString = "F07D0079"
string hexString2= "F07F"
```

I need each string to look like:
79007DF0 &
7FF0 respectively.

For the love of god i don't know why they're stored in strings, but they are.
***This is a little endian/big endian issue but since it's in a string i can't use standard functions to reverse the order can I?***

Is there any easy way to do this?

```
std::string swapValues(string originalHex)
{
  string swappedHex;
  //what to do here.
  return swappedHex;
}
```

Comment: As if there weren't any stdlib functions operating on strings...

Comment: "but since it's in a string i can't use standard functions to reverse the order can I?" Err... why would that be a problem? Stl stuff works with stl containers and string is such container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use the `append` member function.

```
std::string reverse_pairs(std::string const & src)
{
    assert(src.size() % 2 == 0);
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(src.size());

    for (std::size_t i = src.size(); i != 0; i -= 2)
    {
        result.append(src, i - 2, 2);
    }

    return result;
}
```

(As an exercise in extensibility, you can make the "`2`" a parameter, too.)

If you want to do it in-place, you can use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

First check that the length is even (if it hasn't already been sanitised):

```
assert(hex.length() % 2 == 0);
```

Then reverse the string:

```
std::reverse(hex.begin(), hex.end());
```

Now the bytes are in the correct order, but the digits within each are wrong, so we need to swap them back:

```
for (auto it = hex.begin(); it != hex.end(); it += 2) {
    std::swap(it[0], it[1]);
}
```

Comment: Isn't using `it[0]` asking for trouble? Who says that exists? Why not use `std::iter_swap` instead?

Comment: @KerrekSB: The standard says it exists (for random-access iterators), and is equivalent to `*(it+0)`. You could use `iter_swap` or various other alternatives, if this doesn't appeal to your aesthetics.

Comment: Nice, I never knew there was a []-operator for random access iterators. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with something overly clever for this:

```
std::string swapValues(const std::string& o)
{
    std::string s(o.length());

    if (s.length() == 4) {
        s[0] = o[2];
        s[1] = o[3];
        s[2] = o[0];
        s[3] = o[1];
      return s;
    }
    if (s.length() == 8) {
        // left as an exercise
    }

    throw std::logic_error("You got to be kidding me...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be library functions available (a naive string manipulation might be no good):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main() {
    std::string hex32 = "F07D0079";
    std::string hex16 = "F07F";
    std::uint32_t u32 = std::strtoul(hex32.c_str(), 0, 16);
    std::uint16_t u16 = std::strtoul(hex16.c_str(), 0, 16);
    // Here we would need to know the endian of the sources.
    u32 = ntohl(u32);
    u16 = ntohs(u16);
    std::cout << std::hex << u32 << ", " << u16 << '\n';
}
```

Linux/Little Endian

Any function operating on the strings must know the target platform (hence there is no general solution)

Comment: This only works if `ntohl` and `ntohs` are part of your compiler library.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sure but, it depends on the platform/machine anyway